# How to make a query for getting the specific rows with the latest time column value

Tags: sqlite

Below is my sample data, I would like to get the host:value pair with the latest time.

```
+------+-------+-------+
| HOST | VALUE | TIME  |
+------+-------+-------+
|  A   |  100  | 13:40 |
|  A   |  150  | 13:00 |
|  A   |  222  | 13:23 | 
|  B   |  210  | 13:55 |
|  B   |  300  | 13:44 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Wanted to get only rows with the latest time value for the each host column value.
The result should be like:
A 150 13:40
B 210 13:55

I think there are several analytical function to achieve this requirement in Oracle but I'm not sure what can I do in SQLite.

Can you let me know how I can make a query?

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ANSI-compliant way of performing your query which should run on *all* versions of SQLite.  For a potentially shorter solution see the answer by @CL.

```
SELECT t1.HOST || '-' || t1.VALUE || '-' || t1.TIME AS HOSTVALUETIME
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT HOST, MAX(TIME) AS MAXTIME
    FROM table
    GROUP BY HOST
) t2
ON t1.HOST = t2.HOST AND t1.TIME = t2.MAXTIME
ORDER BY t1.HOST DESC
```

**Output:**

```
+---------------+
| HOSTVALUETIME |
+---------------+
|  A-100-13:50  |
|  B-210-13:55  |
+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I just only want to get the rows with the latest time info, and it should be based on the each host. I was trying to go over WHERE / Group by clause. In Oracle, there are aggregate function such as Partition by or LAG, but I want to know something for SQLite.

Comment: I meant Window function(Analytical).

Comment: Update your question and be clear about what you need.

Comment: Added. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to get. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, MAX() selects from which row in a group the other column values come:

```
SELECT Host,
       Value,
       MAX(Time)
FROM TheNameOfThisTableIsSoSecretThatICantTellYou
GROUP BY Host;
```